# How to allow '%' to pass in IIS

Tags: django, url, iis

I have a web app developed using DJANGO. Everything works well on the DJNAGO testing server. However, I tried to host it on IIS web server and it works only one problem I am having.

I have one form (user input) and I want to allow the users to input wildcard such as SCA80%. The problem is that I get 404 error and it seems that IIS blocks it because the URL contains % sign.

How can I make IIS don't check for the % regardless of the security issue concerns? Is there any simple solution to fix it?

That's how the URL looks like when I send my request with a wildcard:

> /pareto/article-description/SAC80%25/?type=failure&is_article_desc=True

If I remove the %25 and I put the entire SAC80RKEU211 everything works. Even if I am on the django developing server the %25 works. But not on IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by encoding the values that I am sending such as % and decoding it so it will replace the value %

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the IIS has introduced URL filtering rules for security reasons.'%' is blocked by default as part of security reason in URL.

I suggest you could try to use below config setting to allow the '%'.

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

If this don't solve your issue, please post the details error message and status codes for us to find out the solution.

Comment: I didn't solve my problem. What did solve it is use encoding and decoding or replace the value %.